# Weather API - Add parameters to HTML form with GET

Tags: html, forms, api, url, get

I simply want to submit a HTML form with GET in order to redirect to another URL. However, when submitting, the GET method adds a question mark.

I am using form-input as parameters for the URL, so POST is not an option (I think). Likewise, the form should be able to take a input from the user and then redirect based on that. I am using Metaweather API, which requires ending on `/api/location/(woeid)/`, hence I can't allow question mark from GET method. Currently, I have no luck adding any parameters other than question mark.

Example of valid URL: https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/ (Notice: no question mark)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="GET" target="_blank" action="https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Location..">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Desired outcome: If you write "44418" in input, you will be redirected to  `https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/`

Note: I already have the CORS/XMLHttpRequest/JSON.parse working, I am only trying to enable users to submit/search for a location themselves.

TL;DR: How do I (enable users to) add parameters to a URL without question marks and other "side effects" of GET method?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution for you problem:

```
<form method="GET" target="_blank" 
action="https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/" 
onsubmit="location.href = this.action + this.txt.value; return false;">
<input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" placeholder="Location..">
</form>
```

Comment: My Pleasure...!